# In react-chartjs-2 package, how to enable a reset zoom button for Line Chart. Do in react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

```
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';
    const chartRef = useRef<typeof Line>(null);
function handleResetZoom() {
        if (chartRef && chartRef.current) {
            chartRef.current.resetZoom();
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Line options={options} data={props.lineData} height={'100vh'} />
            <button onClick={handleClick}>toggle</button>
            <button onClick={handleResetZoom}>Reset Zoom</button>
        </>
    );
```

Here, I get following error : Property 'resetZoom' does not exist on type 'TypedChartComponent<"line">'.  TS2339.

I tried to put Line in type of useRef hook.`